# Unable to install Blaze Advisor .Net on Windows 10

Tags: blaze-advisor

I am a .net developer and my first preference will be using Blaze Advisor .Net . I have been trying to run "Blaze Advisor Builder 7.2.6 for .NET" from icon installed on Desktop but nothing happens.

I have installed Blaze Advisor .Net 7.2.6 on Windows 10 from MSI file Advisor.NETx64Setup.msi

Then I went to folder "C:\Blaze_net\Advisor72NET\bin" (path where I have installed Blaze Advisor) and ran "verifyInstall.bat", here I got errors which I resolved one by one. Below are the details

1)

> Could not load file or assembly vjslib

Resolved this error by
installing 64 bit of Visual J# Redistributable

2)

> The type initializer for 'java.lang.System' threw an exception. --->
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load DLL 'vjsnativ'

Resolved this error by copying three dll from path

```
 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vjscor.dll 
 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vjslib.dll 
 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vjsnativ.dll

 to path C:\Blaze_net\Advisor72NET\bin\applications
```

3)

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'java.lang.System' threw an exception. --->
>   System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format.

Resolved this error by running "registerDotNet40Support.bat" file

4) Now the error that i am stuck on is

> Error verifying the Blaze Advisor Installation Additional info :
>   Unable to determine installation directory for product
>   'NdAdvisorCommon'. The product may not be installed properly or the
>   installation registry entries are missing or corrupted.
>
> Check that the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Fair
>   Isaac\Blaze Advisor.NET\Installed Assemblies\com.blazesoft.AdvCommon,
>   Version=7.2.336.60, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a3597fa6e7f2b580'
>   exists.

I have installed "Blaze Advisor" by file downloaded from net Advisor.NETx64Setup.msi and I assume it must have installed it correctly, I can see desktop icon 'Blaze Advisor Builder 7.2.6 for .NET' getting created which doesn't run but.

I can't find any registry entry with name "Fair Issac".

Now what should I do to get over this issue? Installation shouldn't be so complex right.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninsatalled Blaze Advisor and RAN the msi file through command prompt in "Run as Administrator" mode. This way the issue got resolved and I am able to run "Blaze Advisor". 
Note that if you just double click the MSI file it will not install correctly.
Thanks